# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on windows 10, Chrome version 80. I have installed chrome driver compatible with chrome version 80. When I was running the selenium code in eclipse, it was giving error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

So, I have uninstalled all other version of chrome I was having except chrome version 80 but it didn't work.

For resolving this issue we have to set path for Chrome binary. Use `setBinary` function for setting the path of your chrome executable file and Use `setProperty` for setting the path of chrome driver. Please see the image attached

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as Java instead of C#?

Comment: Thank you very much for for your response. It seems it doesn't work even I set binarylocation to default folder that chrome installed, I.e. C:\users\user\....\Chrome. Problem had been workaround by duplicating Chrome folder to D:\ and set BinaryLocation accordingly.